# Automate version filenames check up in snowflake schemachange

Tags: numbers, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, version, schemachange

I have multiple feature branches are under development and will be deployed to different release branches in Snowflake. The files are named with version number in order to use Schemachange.
CICD pipelines are running in Azure DevOps. Is there any method can automate check up if the version number is larger than the max version number in the Snowflake schemachange history?

Using Python or Yaml